# How can I make a Java regex all or nothing?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to make a regex all or nothing in the sense that the given word must EXACTLY match the regular expression - if not, a match is not found.

For instance, if my regex is:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z|0-9|_]*
```

Then I would want to match:

```
cat9
cat9_
bob_____
```

But I would NOT want to match:

```
cat7-
cat******
rango78&&
```

I want my regex to be as strict as possible, going for an all or nothing approach. How can I go about doing that?

EDIT: To make my regex absolutely clear, a pattern must start with a letter, followed by any number of numbers, letters, or underscores. Other characters are not permitted. Below is the program in question I am using to test out my regex.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z|0-9|_]*");

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String result = "";


    while(!result.equals("-1")){

        result = in.nextLine();

        Matcher m = p.matcher(result);

        if(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well the most strict match from the information so far would be the regex `^cat9 cat9_ bob___$`. Is that what you want? Do you have other examples of text that should match and not match?

Comment: Do you mean you want to match over multiple lines? match every line?

Comment: Java uses `\pL` to match a letter code point, not A-Z.  It also uses `\pN` to match a numeric code point.

Comment: Just a question for you (since you wrote it), what does `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z|0-9|_]* ` mean to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that if you use `String.matches(regex)`, then you will get the effect you are looking for. The documentation says that `matches()` will return true only if the **entire** string matches the pattern.

Comment: @Waffles: As a word of caution, you'll probably want to remove the `|` character from the second character class. Inside the class it doesn't act as alternation, it's just a regular character, and will thus match a literal `|` in a string.

Comment: @eldarerathis: Good catch...I don't use regexes very often, so I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

The regex won't match the second example. It's already strict, since * and & are not in the allowed set of characters.

It may match a prefix, but you can avoid this by adding '$' to the end of the regex, which explicitly matches end of input. So try,

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z|0-9|_]*$
```

This will ensure the match is against the entire input string, and not just a prefix.

Comment: Note though: As I noted in my comment on the other answer, the `|` is not really doing what I think the OP intended. It's used twice as though for alternation, but inside a character class it will match a literal `|` character.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `\w` is the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. And you need to anchor to the end of the string like so:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]\\w*$")
```